# @font face stopped working after server switch

Tags: css, wordpress

I've just switched my wordpress website from one server to another by doing a back up of the main section (every single file basically) and the PHP database and then restoring it through cPanel.

http://findarealman.com

for some reasons, my fonts stopped working even though the css and folder structure stayed exactly the same and they were working perfectly fine before.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'calibriregular';
src: url('/skins/fonts/calibri/calibri-webfont.eot');
src: url('/skins/fonts/calibri/calibri-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/skins/fonts/calibri/calibri-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/skins/fonts/calibri/calibri-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/skins/fonts/calibri/calibri-webfont.svg#calibriregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what could have happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the paths would be wrong? Maybe because of the absolute path. If this is Wordpress then logically the files would be in the theme folder and not outside of the wordpress install. For troubleshooting, I would check if the files have been copied over first, and if their path is right, if that's the case you can check in your browser inspector whether the files have been loaded or not, and see from there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can think of something else ... most servers (IIS for sure) doesn't provide `woff` MIME type automatically. You should add it on the main node for all websites, or you can choose to add it on a specific website.

In IIS manager > MIME types > add: .woff

```
application/font-woff
```

Since you are running Php I assume your server runs apache => look in httpd.conf or .htaccess

```
AddType application/font-woff .woff
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I figured it out. As you mentioned Pim and as I suspected as well, it was indeed the paths to the files.

although the skins sub-folder mentioned above was in the same folder with the css file, for some reason it was trying to GET the fonts going ROOT/skins/fonts instead of just going "current folder"/skins/fonts.

No idea why this is tough. Any suggestions?

And thanks for the asnwers Tim/Pim